# Yii2 saving multiple files

Tags: pdo, yii2

I'm try to save multiple files (manual: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html)

Here is my controller code:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->thumb = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'thumb');
        $model->gallery = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'gallery');
        $model->thumb->saveAs('uploads/' . $model->thumb->baseName . '.' . $model->thumb->extension);
        foreach ($model->gallery as $file) {
            $file->saveAs('uploads/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);
        }
        if($model->validate() && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

But it gives me this exception:

```
Database Exception – yii\db\Exception

SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
The SQL being executed was: UPDATE `project` SET `thumb`='deliver.png', `gallery`=:qp1, `total_square`=221.4, `living_square`=133.6, `price`=150000, `floor`=1 WHERE `id`=1
Error Info: Array
(
[0] => HY093
[1] => 0
)
↵
Caused by: PDOException

SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

in /var/www/map.dev/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php at line 846
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You are trying to save **Array** of UploadedFile objects (gallery) to database field.

Comment: @ZeiZ yes. $model->thumb and $model->gallery must be objects (in DB will object name). Single image works normally (in SQL request you can see filled thumb field), but in gallery field ":qp1". Maybe something with server configuration, but I dont know((